# How do I use replace command in Linux to occurrences number to letter?

Tags: linux

Can some one give me a command that will look for any digit 0-9 and replace it with the corresponding letter A-J. For example, “one is 1 two is 2” would come out “one is B two is C”.

Answer (score 5):

You can pipe it to `tr '0-9' 'A-J'`.

```
$ echo one is 1 two is 2 | tr '0-9' 'A-J'
one is B two is C
```

See `man tr` for more details.